# XSD validating attribute is equal to a parent attribute

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I need to create an XSD that validates the value in a specific complex type with a parent node.

In this specific case the XML will look like this:

```
<ROOT>
  <INFO>
      <REGIONDESC>
        <REGION VALUE="001" DESCRIPTION="Description 1" />
        <REGION VALUE="002" DESCRIPTION="Description 2" />
        <REGION VALUE="003" DESCRIPTION="Description 3" />    
      </REGIONDESC>
      ...Other Nodes..
  </INFO>
  <DETAILS>
      <REGIONDETAILS>
        <REGIONID VALUE="001"/>
        ...Other Nodes..
      </REGIONDETAILS>
  </DETAILS>
</ROOT>
```

I need validate that "REGIONID" value must be equal to some "REGIONDESC/REGION@VALUE".
Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible using the `key` and `keyref` mechanism.  If you can share the schema you have come up with so far then we can explain what you'd need to add to define the cross-references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the definition of the ROOT element, define an xs:key with selection xpath="INFO/REGIONDESC/REGION", and field xpath="@VALUE"; and a corresponding xs:keyRef with selection xpath="DETAILS/REGIONDETAILS/REGIONID" and field xpath="@VALUE".